# Detaching limbs on existing rigify/model

Tags: modeling, rigging

I've got a bunch of zombies, with a low-poly model (we'll be rotoscoping over this later) and rigged with the built-in Rigify tool. Halfway thru my current shot, one of my heroes will be cutting limbs and heads off a few of them. Is there an easy way to detach these parts of the rig? I'm not very familiar with the finer details of how it works, so all the interconnected relationships between deform bones and controllers make the arms and neck deform very badly when I just move the controllers. My best solution right now is to have an alternate head and arms that stay off-camera until the frame before the cut, then pop into place in one frame and drop to the side (or perhaps fly thru the air - depending). I can make it work, but it seems like a clunky work-around. For a good solution, I feel like I need to either customize the rig (way outside my comfort zone currently) or I need to break the body into components and animate them manually, without a rig at all. Rigging geniuses - what would you recommend?

Comment: I would do what you have described. Fake it with a duplicated separate arm and head. Instead of moving the objects away from the camera you can keyframe the visibility (example of drawing a gun: https://youtu.be/Mf1Sh_nPSas). To remove the head or limb you can use the *Mask* modifier or just swap the mesh/toggle visibility (you can bind 2 meshes to the same armature and just show one). There are also Bone Constraints (Child Of, Copy Transformation). With them you can make the fake arm/head automatically follow the real arm/head.